# My mac's hostname keeps getting reset to default

Tags: terminal, network, dns, mojave

My mac's default hostname is `Scott-Johnson.local`. In the sharing system preferences, I set the hostname to `felucia.local`, which takes as expected. However, at some point in the future (usually due to either a restart or waking up from sleep), it resets to `Scott-Johnson.local`. I have also tried the following in the terminal:

```
sudo scutil –-set HostName felucia

sudo scutil –-set LocalHostName felucia

sudo scutil –-set ComputerName felucia
```

Again, it will take for a while, but then reset.

My suspicion is that this is a router problem (i.e. I can assign my computer a static IP instead of DHCP when on my local network). Unfortunately, though, this is a laptop, and I will often use it on other networks where I don't have this ability. How can I verify that this will work outside of the network within my control?

Comment: What do you mean "it's *default* hostname"?  Mac (computers in general) don't come with a pre-set hostname; it's something that has to be set.  Also, prior to setting it, what do you get with the command `scutil --get LocalHostName`?

Comment: It's a former work computer that I purchased from my old company. The original hostname that it came with was `Scott-Johnson.local`, so that's what I meant by "default hostname". It keeps getting set back to this, and I'm not sure why. Prior to manually changing the hostname, `scutil --get LocalHostName` returns `Scott-Johnson`.

Comment: It's most likely a DHCP/DNS issue then.  In your network (home/work) you're setting the host name.  When you go to other networks, it won't try to assign this host name (provided you set it manually as you describe) because those networks won't "know" your MAC address/IP/host name.  That said, since you "inherited" this MacBook, you should do a clean install and set up everything per your preferences.

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211793/device-name-on-router-is-different-than-os-x-hostname/303411#303411

Comment: @jwir3 Perhaps it's something in a plist file that is overriding what you are trying to set manually via terminal. I'm assuming since you purchased this from your work that they were using some sort of management software to control macOS. I'd highly recommend wiping that machine and installing a fresh copy of macOS. But, if you don't want to go that route then check the files under
/Library/Preferences
Find out what software is used to manage Mac's and let us know. This would help identify the problem.

Comment: @BsdHelper I did a grep through `/Library/Preferences` and found instances of `Scott-Johnson2`, but nothing that says `Scott-Johnson`. I changed the instances of `Scott-Johnson2` to `felucia`, but with no luck. :(

Comment: @jwir3 By you saying "I did a grep through..." I take that as you actually grepped that directory for Scott-Johnson. What I meant was physically open the directory in Finder and look at all the PLIST files in there. Search on Google for part of their name or the PLIST label located inside. The goal is to find out what software was used to manage that system. It seems to have a set a preference file somewhere that keeps resetting the hostname. Ask someone at work what they used to manage Mac's and we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try these two steps:

1) First edit the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

`sudo pico -w /etc/sysctl.conf`

and add the line:

`kern.hostname=felucia`

2) Then do this:

`sudo sysctl -w kern.hostname=felucia`

The first command sets the hostname that should be saved after reboot.

The second command sets the hostname immediately.

I'm not positive this will help, but it's worth trying.

Comment: Hm, no joy here. It still got set back to `Scott.Johnson`. :(

Comment: Rats! I was really hopeful that would fix it, although I have to admit I was not overly optimistic it would. Sort of a Hail-Mary attempt. I'm not sure this is solvable any way other than writing a `launchd` script that will check it periodically and reset it when it goes wrong, which is far from ideal. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score -1):

Try `scutil --set LocalHostName`

should prompt you for sudo perms

`scutil --get LocalHostName` still was the incorrect setting after I just ran `hostname`

Comment: The OP hgas already used sudo to run the command