# How to I delete WINS name from Network > Advanced > WINS

Tags: mojave

I'm unable to clear the NetBIOS and Workgroup names (when I try, the current NetBIOS name appears grayed out, and always returns, even after I press "Apply"). I've already issued the command

sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.netbiosd.plist

I don't have any file sharing enabled, nor is there an active directory configured.

Comment: See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303411/119271).  There's also no need to remove the netbios plist.  Out of curiosity, if you're not using it, why are you trying to change/delete it?

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find anything on that page that applies to NetBIOS. I would like to remove the WINS name for the sake of … removing the reference? It's pretty clear that the NetBIOS name is stored in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist However, after deleting the file and restarting, it was restored. How can I make this change permanent? This seems to be a common problem, judging from searches on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the solution was to

1. Remove all the NetBIOS name entries in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist (there was one for every interface)
2. Killall -9 cfprefsd
3. Issue the

   sudo defaults delete/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist

   command for good measure.
4. Restart

I hope this can help others.