# Incorrect hostname keeps appearing in sharing preferences

Tags: network, dns, sharing, file-sharing, bonjour

**Problem:**

I've got two macs in the same network. One of them is often not discoverable via the Finder or Apple Music (shared library). I noticed that this mac has incorrect hostnames in the sharing preferences. When I change the hostname in the text field to *bestHostname*, the blacked out parts won't change. Instead they show something like *phils-imac.domain*.

The other mac is always discoverable and sharing preferences show up the correct hostname.

**What I tried:**

When I type `sudo hostname`into the terminal, the correct hostname appears (the purpled out one). I even tried `sudo scutil --set HostName bestHostname` to set the hostname via terminal, but system preferences still does not change it.

I even restarted the mac. Nothing helped.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Specifically, see this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303411/119271

Comment: @Allen, this led me to the solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/323696/215688 (same question as you mentioned, but different answer).

Comment: If you use that answer, check your router as you may have a static IP mapping with an assigned hostname - or it may be caching the old host in DHCP.  Flush it out and it will get the new name from the hostname value on your Mac.